# num2date does not support 'months since...'

Tags: python, netcdf4

Hello i have a neetcdf4 file with monthly precipitation data for over 10 years.
what i am trying to do is :

1. read the file
2. select a subset area based on longitude latitude
3. i need to calculate the moving average per 3 years
4. plot the results

> ```
> dataset = Dataset('test.nc','r',format='NETCDF4')
> lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]
> lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
> times = dataset.variables['time'][:]
> times_units = dataset.variables['time'].units
> prep_solide = dataset.variables['PREC'][:,:,:]
> prec_units =dataset.variables['PREC'].units
>
> dates = num2date(times[:],' months since 1801-01-01 00:00:00')
> ```

The error i keep getting is

> ValueError: unsupported time units

is there any other way to fix this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed "months" is not supported by `num2date` function. To be honest, what is the meaning of 2 months since `1800-01-01 00:00:00` anyway? Is it `1800-03-01 00:00:00` or something else (1 month = 365.25/12 days and hence `1800-03-02 02:21:00`)?

In any case, I would make the dates with my own function. For example, in your case:

```
dates = [datetime.datetime(1800,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(seconds = 365.25/12*24.0*3600.0*float(val)) for val in times]
```

As I do not know what is the value of 1 month in seconds in your data, I used 365.25/12.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In fact in my case the meaning of two month is 1800-03-01 00:00:00 . But i believe that with the way you presented it i can extract the month and the year for my analysis easily regardless of the  day and hour . Thank you so much